# App error displaying blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my app's idea is simple. a user inputs text and then it gets diplayed and saved into the db. The problem am having is that it displays blank. I have a lot of code so am going to put the bare minimum.

my server :

```
// dependencies
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var hash = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local' ).Strategy;
var meetupsController = require('./meetups-controller');
// mongoose
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mean-auth');

// user schema/model
var User = require('./models/user.js');

// create instance of express
var app = express();

// require routes
var routes = require('./routes/api.js');
app.get('/api/meetups', meetupsController.list);
app.post('/api/meetups', meetupsController.create);
// define middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// configure passport
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// routes
app.use('/user/', routes);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'index.html'));
});

// error hndlers
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  }));
});




app.use(bodyParser());
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));

//REST API

module.exports = app;
```

my main angular controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/api/meetups', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/logout', {
      controller: 'logoutController',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
      controller: 'registerController',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/one', {
      template: '<h1>This is page one!</h1>',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/two', {
      template: '<h1>This is page two!</h1>',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) {
      AuthService.getUserStatus()
      .then(function(){
        if (next.access.restricted && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
          $location.path('/login');
          $route.reload();
        }
      });
  });
});

myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });

  $scope.meetups = []

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }
}]);
```

my html partial

```
<body>
  <div id='main' ng-controller="loginController">
      <form ng-Submit="post()">
         <input required type="text" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by" /> 
         <textarea required maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
      </form>
      <div id="post-stream">
         <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
         <div class='post' ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
             <p>{{post.created_by}} says {{post.text}} at {{post.created_at}}</p>
         </div>
         <div ng-controller="logoutController">
           <a ng-click='logout()' class="btn btn-default">Logout</a>
         </div>
          <div ng-controller="logoutController">
           <a ng-click='gotoregister()' class="btn btn-default">register</a>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="meetupsController">
     <h1>There are {{meetups.length}} meetups</h1>
     <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="meetup in meetups">
       {{meetup.name}}
     </li>
     </ul>
    <form ng-submit="createMeetup()">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Meetup name" ng-model="meetupName"></input>
       <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form> 
  </div>
</body>
```

please help

Comment: is there any message over console?

Comment: no can u help me please

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a need for logoutController more than once...

Comment: the controller has to be set on the parent element ..here the controller is set on div...this can cause as issue..try setting controller on body tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "displays blank", but there is likely an issue with these lines:

```
Meetup.query(function (results) {
  $scope.meetups = results;
});

$scope.meetups = []
```

If `$scope.meetups` is assigned `results`, you may be overwriting that value with `$scope.meetups = []`. Remember that the $resource will resolve asynchronously, so assignments won't exactly happen in the order they are written. Try removing the `$scope.meetups = []` line.

Comment: If you use a `console.log($scope.meetups)` in the controller, try placing one both in the `.query` block and outside of it, what do you get?

Comment: here is what i get Array[19]
0
:
Resource
1
:
Resource
2
:
Resource
3
:
Resource
$$hashKey
:
"object:18"
__v
:
0
_id
:
"58332ba11e58a60f78bdf33d"
__proto__
:
Object
4
:
Resource
5
:
Resource
6
:
Resource
7
:
Resource
8
:
Resource
9
:
Resource
10
:
Resource
11
:
Resource
12
:
Resource
13
:
Resource
14
:
Resource
15
:
Resource
16
:
Resource
17
:
Resource
18
:
Resource
$promise
:
c
$resolved
:
true
length
:
19

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: anyone got any idea

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by "displays blank"? When you print out {{meetup}} in your html view, does anything appear? Is that what is showing as "blank"?